# Meteor template render inside a bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have this problem when I'm trying to show a value get from a collection inside a Bootstrap Modal Dialog.

This is the code for the client side javascript:

```
Template.Modal_edit_client.edit_client_name = function() {
    var c = Clients.findOne({_id: Session.get("current_editing")});
    return c.name;
};
```

and this is the template:

```
<template name="Modal_edit_client">
    <div id="Modal_edit_client" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3>Editar cliente</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="edit_client" action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <input id="edit_client_name" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" type="text" value="{{edit_client_name}}">
                    {{edit_client_name}}
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a id="edit_client_cancel" href="#" class="btn">Cancelar</a>
            <a id="edit_client_save" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The page didn't render and this is what show the conosole:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined 
Exception from Meteor.flush: TypeError: Cannot call method 'firstNode' of undefined
    at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?ba288278f8e36e3529187cea4590001f50ef0f95:545:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?ba288278f8e36e3529187cea4590001f50ef0f95:860:13
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps-utils.js?0c00e493224f891c3d6c82a23693ba55e0f47611:78:31
    at _.extend.run (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:19:20)
    at rerun (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps-utils.js?0c00e493224f891c3d6c82a23693ba55e0f47611:78:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:71:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore/underscore.js?017a0dea6ebb07eec57a1541a0fd524665e769bd:79:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:69:13
    at Array.forEach (native) logging.js:30
Exception from Meteor.flush: TypeError: Cannot call method 'firstNode' of undefined
    at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?ba288278f8e36e3529187cea4590001f50ef0f95:545:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?ba288278f8e36e3529187cea4590001f50ef0f95:860:13
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps-utils.js?0c00e493224f891c3d6c82a23693ba55e0f47611:78:31
    at _.extend.run (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:19:20)
    at rerun (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps-utils.js?0c00e493224f891c3d6c82a23693ba55e0f47611:78:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:71:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore/underscore.js?017a0dea6ebb07eec57a1541a0fd524665e769bd:79:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:69:13
    at Array.forEach (native) logging.js:30
Exception from Meteor.flush: TypeError: Cannot call method 'firstNode' of undefined
    at Object.Spark.renderToRange (http://localhost:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?ba288278f8e36e3529187cea4590001f50ef0f95:545:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/spark/spark.js?ba288278f8e36e3529187cea4590001f50ef0f95:860:13
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps-utils.js?0c00e493224f891c3d6c82a23693ba55e0f47611:78:31
    at _.extend.run (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:19:20)
    at rerun (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps-utils.js?0c00e493224f891c3d6c82a23693ba55e0f47611:78:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:71:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore/underscore.js?017a0dea6ebb07eec57a1541a0fd524665e769bd:79:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/deps/deps.js?d804638a4633c2f6488827923ba5fbd00f07d518:69:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

I think the problem shows in the first line, the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. Is there a way to wait until the  `c.name !== undefined` amd render the template after that?

Comment: For large code, [gist](http://gist.github.com) is a good option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When meteor loads the first time on the browser it doesn't have any data from the server in the collections, but the templates will still render. As with when your Session isn't set. So you need to handle the case while its loading (just check that there is a record before trying to read `name`

```
Template.Modal_edit_client.edit_client_name = function() {
    var c = Clients.findOne({_id: Session.get("current_editing")});
    if(c) return c.name;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful but I still can't see the value rendered in the template.

Comment: Have you set the Session hash for "current_editing" and does it correspond to an id in your collection? If you run `Clients.findOne({_id: Session.get("current_editing")});` in your webkit console does it give you your document?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I want, gives me the ID of the document.

Comment: This actually works, I restart the server and is working now so thank you!